# 0x0A after 0x0D when reading file

Tags: c++

I read a file and find that there are `0x0D` after any `0x0A`. 
I only know that it is the windows that do the convertion.

But I have used the binary mode, it cannot prevent it?

`ifstream input(inputname, ios::binary);input.get(ch);`

How do I avoid it. I only want to get the `\n`.

How about write file?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Why would you open a file in binary mode if you want text conversions done on it?! If you want it processed as text, open it in text mode.

Comment: So I have to use the read funtion, is it?

Comment: And the 0x0D will disappear? Sorry, my concept isn't very clear,

Comment: No, but at least you'll be doing things that make sense, rather than asking the system to do something and then complaining when it does precisely what you asked it to do.

Comment: Then how can I determine whether 0D is the file's data? Only can be done by the `if` after the 0A?Is there some elegant way to do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to read a file that consists of lines of text and you just want to get the each line without any line endings? Or do you want to read a raw binary file but suppress any `0x0A` that comes after an `0x0D`?

Comment: I want to caculate each character frequency in a file.I used the array's index as the (unsigned int)char.(suppose all ascii code)

Comment: So you want to avoid counting any `0x0D`? Or you want to avoid counting an `0x0D` if, and only if, it appears after an `0x0A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a system that does use `\r\n` line endings then opening a file in *text* mode will cause the system to automatically convert these to the standard `\n` without `\r`. Opening a file in binary mode prevents this conversion.

If you're on a system that does *not* use this convention then there's no mode that will convert the line endings. You will have to convert them manually yourself or preprocess the file using an external tool.

---

If you want to detect whether a file uses `\r\n` you'll have to do it manually. Scan through the text file and see if every `\n` is preceded by a `\r`.

As an alternative, instead of trying to preemptively detect what kind of line endings a file uses, you could simply add logic in your processing code to specially handle `\r` followed by `\n`. Something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    if ('\r' == text[i] && (i+1<n) && '\n' == text[i+1])
        ++i; // skip carriage return, just handle newline
    if ('\n' == text[i])
        handle newline...
    else
        handle other characters
}
```

Comment: Whoa, don't know how I missed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. If you use binary mode, `ios::binary` tells the library that you want to read the file as it is in binary (uncooked, raw).
Using msdos (some people nowadays call it windows-nt) lines in text-files are terminated by 0d0a. So if you dont want to see this two chars, you have to open the file in text-mode (just omit the ios::binary).
 Or you have to convert these files to unix-style by some utilities like dos2unix, but then, if you are on a windows system, e.g. notepad may not be able to display this files as expected...